# What do Hub represents in SignalR

Tags: c#, signalr

I was just reading Hubs at SignalR(https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) but I couldn't get the clear idea what it is. Is it like groups in chat or something else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I haven't used it but basically it's a "real time" communication technology for communicating between the client (javascript, silverlight, .NET) and ASP.NET. Currently there are 3 methods for "real time" communication (think chat application): polling, long polling, and HTML5 WebSockets. SignalR adds an abstraction layer and leverages all 3 of these methods depending on browser support and context. Here's an article describing the 3 methods (and how SignalR helps):
http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2011/11/29/Techniques-for-real-time-client-server-communication.aspx

And here's an article from Hanselman (and a functioning demo!) on how to use it:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx

Another:
http://jordanwallwork.co.uk/2011/10/signalr/

A Hub is a class used for the communication. In javascript you can use a hub like this:

```
$(function() {
    var myConnection = $.connection.myHub;
    $.connection.hub.start();
});
```

In ASP.NET you do this:

```
public class Chat : Hub {
    public void Distribute(string message) {
        Clients.receive(Caller.name, message);
    }
}
```

Both of those snippets were taken from the links referenced above.

Comment: It's a bit hidden away, but the top of this page might help: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs

Answer (score 5):

You can think of Hubs as Asp.NET MVC controllers for perstistent connections between client ([javascript](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs)) and server (hub).

Easy way to send different kinds of messages and data between client and server.

Parameters and return values are automatically serialized to and from JSON on the client side.

Hubs have the concept of adding clients to groups so you could with the methods AddToGroup and RemoveFromGroup create chat room functionality. so you can send messages to all clients in a specific group.

I really recommend downloading the code from [GitHub](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) and looking through the samples. There is a Chat-sample there with rooms (groups).

Answer (score 0):

Hubs are SignalR's high level API that allow both realtime client-to-server *and* server-to-client RPC over HTTP. The hub supports 1-to-many RPC e.g.: all clients, groups of clients, just the caller etc. Transport is over one of the following (best to worst): WebSocket, server sent events, forever frame, long polling.

see: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-034

Answer (score 0):

Was reading up on this to come to a good defined answer about what a hub is and came across this question. Even though there are a lot of answers here they seem to be a bit old in the sense that they dont fully reveal the potential of signalR.

I recently created a **push notification** application with the help of singalR.

Imagine sending an AJAX request where you insert data to a db. If you connect a listner to the db that listens for changes you can then send messages from the server to all connected user about that specific db change...in other word a push notification that something has occurred.

This [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/874240/SignalR-Database-update-notifications-in-ASP-NET-M) gives a good example on how to partially achieve this